# javascript how to use document.getElementById inside tinymce Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

```
ed.on("change", function(ed, o) {

    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    console.log(el);

});
```

for example I want to get an element after the user edit the content, but this `document.getElementById` works on the main document, but how to use it in the context of the tinymce Iframe?, I tought that if I use `document.getElementById` inside that wrapper function, so that should work, but this doesn't work, yep there is a built-in function in tinymce to get elements, but I need to use this `document.getElementById`, to embed a player for example...any toughts?

Comment: do you want to get access to the dom of the iframe in the context of the main document.... main calls iframe dom?

Comment: I don't know how to do it best, any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: both can be done. inside the main context you can reached the document of the iframe with

document.frames (index).document ..newline..
document.frames (ifrName).document ..newline..

<iframe name="ifrName"></iframe>

inside the iframe context you can reach the iframe document simply with

document

Comment: if you want to reach the main context inside the iframe context. you have to call
parent.document  or top.document for the highest frame